# Mysterious hieroglyph in a command of a Spotify process after update

Tags: windows, process, spotify

I've just spotted that right after update spotify starts itself up with a command line that looks like

```
Spotify.exe /UPDATECOMPLETE "䣈!"
```

I can understand the purpose of the `/UPDATECOMPLETE` key there, but what could the mysterious `"䣈!"` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows command line officially uses UTF-16, but sometimes programs mistakenly put other kinds of data there – e.g. UTF-8, ASCII, or just raw binary garbage. Since `䣈!` is U+48C8 U+0021, it might have been just the number 0xC8482100. (If it's a 32-bit system, it could have been a mixup of pointer-to-text vs pointer-to-pointer-to-text.)

Comment: Yep, I think this would be the best assumption unless there is a spotify employee around that can tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

#### What could the mysterious "䣈!" mean?

It means a lane or an alley.

> 䣈

...

> (ancient form of 巷) (interchangeable 衖) a lane, an alley

Source [Unihan data for U+48C8](http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=48C8)

Comment: While you have identified the character, that doesn't really explain what it means in this context...

Comment: But as sarcastic answers go it was a good one :-)